# Combine two ActiveRecord results and sort by a shared joined table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Convo` table and a `GroupMeeting` table that both are associated with a `Msg` table.

I want to find all the instances where the current_user has convos or group_meetings with msgs, combine the two, and then show both together to the user in order of the last msg.created_at

Here I have defined both:

```
@convos = Convo.includes(:msgs).where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", current_user, current_user).where.not(:msgs => { :id => nil }).merge(Msg.order(created_at: :desc))
@group_meetings = current_user.group_meetings.includes(:msgs).where.not(:msgs => { :id => nil }).merge(Msg.order(created_at: :desc))
```

And then combined them together:

```
  @convos = @convos + @group_meetings
```

What I can't figure out is how to now sort them by msg.created_at

I have tried the following:

```
 @convos = (@convos + @group_meetings).sort_by(&:"#{msg.created_at}")
 @convos.order('msg.created_at DESC')
```

These all seem to be server-side sorting though. How can I sort these based off the join table, after the array has been created?

Please let me know if I need to supply any other details. Thank you!!

Comment: are you using ruby-on-rails? if you do, which version?

Comment: @potashin yes - ruby 2.3.1p112  and Rails 5.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
(@convos + @group_meetings).sort_by { |item| item.msgs.minimum(:created_at) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This gives me the error `undefined method msg for #<Convo:0x007f99a14fcd78>` Did you mean? msgs` When I update to pluarlize `msg` it says `undefined method created_at for #<Msg::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f99a6992810> Did you mean? create`

Comment: @gwalshington as they all have multiple `msgs` and not one, by which do you want to arrange the sorting?

Comment: I want to arrange them in order of which has the most recently created msg. It's a chat view - so the user should see their 'chats' in order of which most recently had a msg created

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you - I used that answer, and then put .reverse! at the end to show the most recent first.

Comment: @gwalshington: you can just use `minimum` instead of `maximum`, without `reverse`

Comment: even better. Thank you!!

Comment: I was able to do something similar with sweetened syntax: ```(@convos + @group_meetings).sort_by(&:updated_at).reverse```